# Which is the most efficent way to handle eventListeners?

Tags: javascript, function, click, event-listener

I wrote the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       if(event.target.matches('#open-new-not') || event.target.matches('#close-not')){
            opnNewNot();
       }
       if(event.target-matcheS('#hide-links')){
            hideLinks();
       }
       if(...and so on...){}
});
```

Is it a good solution? Could you please advise how could I handle almost all the eventlisteners in the most simple and efficient way?

Comment: Use the event delegation pattern, such as via jQuery.

Comment: It would probably be more efficient to just assign click listeners to the specific items themselves, otherwise **every** time there is a click anywhere in the document, it runs that handler and checks multiple conditions.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you should be adding the event listeners to each object individually that needs to be listened for, not adding a single global listener that manually checks which target was the source of the trigger.

Comment: and I forgot to say, I am trying to stay on pure JavasScript. At the moment I dont want to add libraries to my webapplication.

Comment: Additionally, since you're only using individual `if` statements (as opposed to `else if`), every condition in the list will be checked even if it matches early on. That's about the most inefficient way you could be doing it.

Comment: @Abion47 yes, you are seeing it right.

Comment: @Herohtar thank you for your suggestion, you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must go this route then I suggest that you use a `switch` statement as opposed to a string of `if`s. Doing so has the added benefit of not interrupting the handling of other events that you are not trying to intercept.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
        case 'open-new-not':
        case 'close-not':
            openNewNot();
            break;
        case 'hide-links':
            hideLinks();
            break;
        // etc
    }
});
```

If I were you though I would heavily consider whether or not I want to capture every `click` event on every element or if I could realistically get away with targeting just a handful of select elements.

Comment: If I understand right, your suggestion is to rather use element.addEventListener('click', function); for each elements that must implement a function on click?

Comment: That is correct. Instead of siphoning all element clicks through your function just find all of the elements you need to manage the events for and attach a new event listener to each one individually.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your suggestion. :) A bit I feel it unflexible as if i have 30 function to assign to different elements, I have to repeat the same code. Anyway, if this is the most efficient... :)

Comment: Since you seem to only be matching IDs then I believe this is the most efficient way to do it. `switch` will break execution on the first match it finds. This way it will only execute the comparisons it needs in order to find the match and will stop.

Comment: Thank you so much, again! :)

Comment: @Roelly You can't get around writing code for each event handler, whether that code is split among different functions or in different chunks of a switch block. From an efficiency standpoint, though, adding a listener to each individual element is better, as you won't have to deal with click events on everything _else_ as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! So be it, just tried to find a DRY solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are matching only ids, there's no point in using event delegation (unless the elements are lazily loaded). Just install the event listeners on the elements themselves, don't use a large chain of `if`/`else` here. Event delegation only makes handling events on many similar elements more efficient.

Comment: In that case event delegation must be used in case of classes for example?

Comment: @Roelly At least it makes more sense for those. Or in general, if you have a text with many `<span>`s or a table with many `<td>`s you don't want to install the handler on each of them.